# CloudKit - How to modify the record created by other user

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit

It was OK in development,
but when I distributed my app by TestFlight, I have had this problem.

While I was checking some failures,
I have guessed that **when a user who didn’t create the record try to modify it, can’t do that.**
By the way, I can **fetch** all record values on Public Database. Only **modification** isn’t performed.

In the picture below, iCloud accounts are written in green areas. I predicted that these have to be same.

[image: Metadata - CloudKit Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npz1S.png)

Now, users are trying to modify a record by the following code:

```
func modifyRecord() {

    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "accountID == %@", argumentArray: [myID!])
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Accounts", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {(records, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("error1: \(error)")
            return
        }

        for record in records! {
        
            /* ↓ New Value */
            record["currentLocation"] = CLLocation(latitude: 40.689283, longitude: -74.044368)

            publicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: {(record, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print("error2: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                print("success!")
            })
        }
    })
}
```

In development, I created and modified all records by myself, so I was not able to find this problem.

#### Versions

Xcode 11.6 / Swift 5

#### Summary

I guessed that **it is necessary to create and modify record by same user ( = same iCloud Account ) in this code.**
Then, could you please tell me how to modify the record created by other user?
In the first place, can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a permissions problem.  In your cloudkit dashboard, go to: Schema > Security Roles

[image: SecurityRoles]

Then under 'Authenticated' (which means a user logged into Icloud)

[image: Authenticated type]

you'll need to grant 'Write' permissions to the relevant record type.  That should fix it!

[image: Permissions]